# How to select particular textfile

Tags: apache-poi

Using Apache POI to parse text documents and search for keywords inside them

Comment: Which type of document you have?(docx, txt, rtf..)

Comment: If your resume have same type of pattern(format) it easy to get the your particular keyword using [Apache POI library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI)

Comment: Is there a way I could run a loop and read each file one by one and then display them if the list of keywords are found ?

Comment: Yes you can do it. What you want to display keywords or file name that contain keywords

Comment: For simple you have to put your all file in a single folder and then create a array of files using `java.io.File`. Iterate the file name one by one and parse the document whatever you want to find in document

Comment: Honestly, I haven't written any java code in a while. I'd like to display the files in which these keywords are found. Could I use hash maps or key formatted arrays to do the same?

Comment: Ok, So how can I help you to get what you want

Comment: Here's the things I'd like to do . 1) Read all the files into an array. 2) Check for specific keywords in these files. 3.) Collect a list of files with these keywords. 4.) Display them one by one. The fourth step could be skipped but I have little idea as to how I would implement the first three.

Comment: Would I give code for that or just explain by sentence

Comment: Code would be very helpful , thank you! I could there by take that idea to implement more things

Comment: That'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just simply create resume parser that parse each document(.doc, .docx) to find given keywords in folder or in sub-folder. Please read the Java-Doc of [HWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocumentCore.html#getDocumentText--).

Here is code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;


public class ResumeParser {
    HWPFDocument document;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    String rootFolderPath;
    Map<String, List<String>> displayContent = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> keywordList;

    public ResumeParser(String rootFolderPath, List<String> keywordList) throws IOException {
        this.rootFolderPath = rootFolderPath;
        this.keywordList = keywordList;
        startParsing();
    }

    public void startParsing() throws IOException {
        createDisplayContent(rootFolderPath);
        printContent(displayContent);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the display content it parse the each file under given folder and
     * also in sub folder. folder
     * 
     * @param rootFolderPath
     *            the root folder path
     */
    public void createDisplayContent(String rootFolderPath) {
        File fileL = new File(rootFolderPath);
        File[] fileArrL = fileL.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileArrL.length; i++) {
            File fileTempL = fileArrL[i];
            if (fileTempL.isFile()) {
                String name = fileTempL.getName();
                String extension = name.substring(name.indexOf('.') + 1, name.length()).toUpperCase();
                if (extension.equals("DOC") || extension.equals("DOCX")) {
                    parseDocFile(fileTempL.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } else if (fileTempL.isDirectory()) {
                createDisplayContent(fileTempL.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    public void parseDocFile(String filePath) {
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            document = new HWPFDocument(fileInputStream);
            String text = document.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
            Iterator<String> iteratorL = keywordList.iterator();
            List<String> matchKeywordListL = new ArrayList<String>();
            String keywordL = "";
            while (iteratorL.hasNext()) {
                keywordL = iteratorL.next().toUpperCase();
                if (text.contains(keywordL)) {
                    matchKeywordListL.add(keywordL.toLowerCase());
                }
            }
            displayContent.put(filePath, matchKeywordListL);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printContent(Map<String, List<String>> displayContent) {
        Iterator<String> iteratorL = displayContent.keySet().iterator();
        String keyL = "";
        while (iteratorL.hasNext()) {
            keyL = iteratorL.next();
            System.out.println("File Name: " + keyL + "  Match Keywords: " + displayContent.get(keyL));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        List<String> keywordListL = new ArrayList<String>();
        keywordListL.add("Java");
        keywordListL.add("PHP");
        keywordListL.add("Andriod");
        keywordListL.add("John");
        new ResumeParser("D:\\Doc", keywordListL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to add keyword to Arraylist and set directory from a request object from a webpage ? Using something like servlets perhaps

Comment: Yes you can add the ArrayList and directory path in session object.

Comment: @JasonBecker Any kind of problem you facing while parsing the document using request object.

Comment: Yet to implement that part. I should be doing that over the next 6-8 hours though. I'll let you know however

Comment: I've implemented the provided answer. Yet , I keep getting a NullPointerException. I've provided the rootFolderPath directly as the folder that contains these word files. Yet,  I keep getting Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: I have a feeling the line , " File fileL = new File(rootFolderPath); " inside the createDisplayContent(String rootFolderPath) function requires a file instead of just a path to a folder , unless I'm wrong. This maybe causing a Null Pointer Exception as fileL remains empty maybe

Comment: Have you print the `rootFolderPath` before the `File` object is create. Is it right? 1)`rootFolderPath` string is `null` or empty then it cause a exception 2) Your folder location is not valid location 3) Your folder have no files

Comment: @Jason Becker You can check the given path is valid or not by using `file.exists()` it return `true` if directory or file is exists otherwise `false`

Comment: Now, I've gotten rid of the NullPointerException. But despite all the files in that folder being word files , I now have a Exception "in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The document is really a OOXML file" Error.

Comment: I've got the output now. I simply removed the , "DOCX", files from my if statement. It seems, DOCX , aren't exactly word files and are docx only for compatibility.

Comment: @JasonBecker Can you share your code snippet and some resume files so I figure out what is the problem on patelganesh48@gmail.com

Comment: Kindly, check your email